# How to pass a nested foreignkey object to a another model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've been stumped for days; hoping one of you wizards can get me out of this pickle..

***TL:DR version***

When using a ForeignKey (many-to-one relationship) in DRF; there is no field to POST the primary key of that parent object in order to assign it to the child instance.

Some symptoms:

- the parent object is accessible via the Admin UI but not in POST requests
- GET requests of existing child objects (created using the admin ui) show the parent object
- raw data or json input have no effect on POST - even including ID explicitly in the POST

***Full context***

I have a model called ExtraSlot

```
class ExtraSlot(models.Model):
    ...
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="employee")
```

this is the serializer

```
class ExtraSlotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         
    employee = EmployeeSerializer(many=True) <-- If I add this it tries to iterate through and errors out - also is a ForeignKey so not many anyway. Just thought I'd try and see if it produced anything unusual.

    class Meta:
        model = ExtraSlot
        fields = (..... 'employee')
                fields = ('__all__') <- also used this to no avail
        depth = 3
```

I'm trying to add an Employee to the model; in the admin panel it is fine. The employee object can be selected. The DRF api doesn't show anything; I've read HTML list input isn't supported which is fine but the employee field as an input (even in raw format) doesn't show at all.

`Employee` extends `User(AbstractBaseUser)` - here is the list error if I try `many=True` and passing the entire serializer.

```
TypeError: 'Employee' object is not iterable
```

(if I try pass EmployeeSerializer with many=True; which makes sense because it should only be one instance. Insanity made me try this)

```
employee = EmployeeSerialzer()
```

passes the entire object as if I want to create a new one?!

I want to allow a user to assign employee to the extraslot.

Please help!

Full model and serializer

```
class WorkingSlot(models.Model):

    starttime = models.DateTimeField()
    finishtime = models.DateTimeField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, blank=True, null= True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, related_name="%(class)s_employee")

    def get_minislots(self):
        #
        
        totaltime = self.finishtime - self.starttime
        return totaltime

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ## overring models save function to dynamically fill the mimi-slot

        total = self.get_minislots()
        minutes = total.total_seconds() / 60
        slots = minutes // 5
        self.minislots = slots
        super(ExtraSlot, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        DynamicSlot.objects.create(extraslot=self)

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.employee) + 's extra slot date: (' + str(self.starttime.date())+')'
```

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])

    user_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())] )

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])

    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('email', 'user_name', 'password', 'password2' , 'first_name',  'last_name', 'mobile_number', 'photo', 'calender_sync_info', 'business' )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(email=validated_data['email'], user_name=validated_data['user_name'])
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        Employee.objects.create(user_id= user.email, 
                                first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                mobile_number=validated_data['mobile_number'],
                                photo='photo',
                                calender_sync_info=validated_data['calender_sync_info'],business=validated_data['business'])
        
        return validated_data
```

**Updated**

this is the GET response of one slot object (which I created in the admin UI) with `employee = EmployeeSerializer()` in the serializer.

```
[
    {
        "starttime": "2021-09-14T21:22:18",
        "finishtime": "2021-09-14T21:22:19",
        "postcode": "e14",
        "minislots": 0,
        "employee": {
            "first_name": "john",
            "last_name": "doe",
            "business": "business1@admin.com"
        }
    }
]
```

this is the response without

```
[
    {
        "starttime": "2021-09-14T21:22:18",
        "finishtime": "2021-09-14T21:22:19",
        "postcode": "e14",
        "minislots": 0,
        "employee": {
            "user": "employee1@admin.com",
            "first_name": "john",
            "last_name": "doe",
            "business": {
                "user": "business1@admin.com",
                "company_name": "business1",
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Maybe I have to pass the `user.email` explicitly which is also the id/pk when the Employee is created?! Then try use it here?

Comment: What is the difference between your `WorkingSlot` and `ExtraSlot` models?

Comment: Sorry Daniel it's the same model. I was trying to simplify as much as possible. This ExtraSlot serializor is again used as a nested foreignkey.

Comment: can you share your actual code + employee serializer as well?

Comment: you cant pass the `many=True` cause you have `one to many` relation, and `ExtraSlot` can have only one `Employee`

Comment: Thanks Ali. Yes I know but after trying everything I wanted to see what it done.

Comment: Hi! Can you share a sample request data? So you want to just specify an employee id instead of one whole employee object?

Comment: I've updated and added two GET responses of an object that was created in the admin ui (only way to currently pass an instance of Employee). I'm starting to think I need to pass the PK/ID of the employee when it's being created?

Comment: Solved it guys lol thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out..

```
class ExtraSlotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = ExtraSlot
    fields = ('__all__')
    depth = 3 <---
```

The issue is with the **depth** parameter. When applied even at depth of 1, the depth of relationships is traversed. What were asking is to iterate through any nested object and return the level of depth we require.

The ForeignKey/Many-to-one therefore expands the entire object not allowing for a primary key id to be passed (posted).

When we remove the depth parameter a field for the ID of the object is available and can be used.

Hope this helps someone in the future.